# Determine which program is accessing network shares?

Tags: windows-10, network-shares, adobe-creative-cloud

On computer A there is a program that makes a network connection to computer B and accesses the network shares.  This occurs 20+ times in less than two seconds.

The event that is fired on computer B is **Event ID: 4648.  This event is generated when a process attempts to log on an account by explicitly specifying that account's credentials.**

I think it has something to do with Adobe Creative Cloud but am unsure. How can I determine which program on computer A is making these requests to computer B?

Comment: Configure Computer A, and launch each application installed on it, one by one until the behavior starts to exhibit itself on Computer B

Comment: Try running `netstat -bo 1` from Command Prompt and note down the process name and PID that's connecting to a particular IP. Or try WireShark.

Comment: @w32sh I tried `netstat -bo 1` and when the connection was made I did not get anything to show from netstat.  I searched for by the computer name and IP address.

Comment: You could try `netstat -abo 1` (from elevated CMD) or try something advanced like WireShark.